# Oracle 12c XML get value from response

Tags: xml, oracle, soap, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL and I need to consume soap web service. I am having trouble extracting p-address value from this response:

```
response xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getAddressForIpResponse xmlns="urn:USR1">
      <p-address xsi:type="xsd:string">11.11.11.11:2222</p-address>
    </getAddressForIpResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried with various combination of EXTRACTVALUE with no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this with `extractvalue`:

```
select extractvalue(
  xmltype(response_string), 
  '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getAddressForIpResponse/p-address',
  'xmlns="urn:USR1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"')
from dual;
```

but `extractvalue` is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACTVALUE.html); so you should use [XMLQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLQUERY.html):

```
select XMLQuery(
  'declare default element namespace "urn:USR1";
   declare namespace soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
   /soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getAddressForIpResponse/p-address/text()'
  passing xmltype(response_string)
  returning content).getStringval()
from dual;
```

Either way you need to supply the default and `soap` namespaces.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b6e4d026ae554e4719b45184fa75db4)

You could also use XMLTable if you're extracting multiple bits of data; here it doesn't add much but it would be something like:

```
select ip_address
from XMLTable (
  XMLNamespaces (
    default 'urn:USR1',
    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soap"
  ),
  '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getAddressForIpResponse/p-address'
  passing xmltype(response_string)
  columns ip_address varchar2(15) path '.');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=372046c27fb9c05b6225f58c716f9770)