# Trying to extract a value from an xmltype but no value returned

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype

This is my oracle SQL :

```
WITH q1(Tdata,paymentinterchangekey) AS
(
  SELECT XMLtype(transportdata, 1), paymentinterchangekey
    FROM bph_owner.paymentinterchange
   WHERE paymentinterchangekey = '137630105'
)
SELECT EXTRACT(q1.Tdata, '/Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/MsgId'),
       q1.Tdata,
       q1.paymentinterchangekey "EE",
       q1.paymentinterchangekey "EE"
  FROM q1;
```

and data is :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Document xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 pain.001.001.03.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" > 
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
<GrpHdr>
<MsgId>SEPA21012022</MsgId>
<CreDtTm>2022-01-20T11:45:59.177</CreDtTm>
<NbOfTxs>12</NbOfTxs>
<CtrlSum>22277.57</CtrlSum>
<InitgPty>
<Nm>
```

Any idea why the EXTRACT value is empty?

Comment: You XML is invalid as it does not close most of the outer elements.

Comment: that is just the sample as it is very big but the GrpHdr tag is closed , the very last tag in the xml is /Document
The SQL runs but returns no value 
thanks

Comment: Then [edit] your question to give a [MRE] which contains a **MINIMAL** example that is valid XML. Otherwise, the answer is "it returns `NULL` because your XML is malformed and putting it into the `XMLTYPE` constructor will raise an exception." which is probably not the answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

`EXTRACT` is deprecated. Use `XMLQUERY` and declare the namespace:

```sql
with q1 ( Tdata, paymentinterchangekey) AS (
  SELECT XMLtype(transportdata),
         paymentinterchangekey 
  from   bph_owner.paymentinterchange 
  where  paymentinterchangekey = '137630105'
)
select XMLQUERY(
         'declare default element namespace "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03";
         /Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/MsgId/text()'
         PASSING q1.Tdata
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ) AS msgid,
       q1.Tdata,
       q1.paymentinterchangekey "EE" 
from   q1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5c906976a8212d590b48bdb33f02dac4)*

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the malformed XML, the issue is that your `Document` node declares a namespace, which you are not including; so you would need to do:

```
EXTRACT(q1.Tdata, '/Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/MsgId',
  'xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"')
```

which would give you

```
<MsgId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">SEPA21012022</MsgId>
```

Presumably you only want the actual value, not the whole node, so you could do:

```
EXTRACT(q1.Tdata, '/Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/MsgId/text()',
  'xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"')
```

to get

```
SEPA21012022
```

However, [the `EXTRACT()` function is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-XML.html), and has been for a long time, so you should use XMLQuery instead:

```
with q1 (Tdata) as (
  SELECT XMLtype(transportdata,1) from paymentinterchange
)
select XMLQuery('
    declare default element namespace "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03";
    /Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/MsgId/text()'
  passing Tdata
  returning content).getstringval()
from q1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0411cb38fc3aac9283dcad923f82fba4)

If you want multiple values from the same XML then look at XMLTable.

---

> So I have now run this as a generic SQL but get the following error : ORA-31011: XML parsing failed ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing LPX-00216: invalid character 195 (0xC3) Error at line 150 ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 283 ORA-06512: at line 1 Is there a way to 'skip' malformed rows?

The rows aren't malformed. The XML declaration says the encoding is ISO-8859-1, which allows any 'Latin-1 (Western)' characters, such as `Ã` - which is encoded as `0xC3`. Your XML is stored as a BLOB, which you are converting to XMLType. But as part of that conversion you are passing `1` as [the `csid` value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/XMLTYPE.html#GUID-59081026-A42A-4352-B5EA-A6E433A51F5E). That represents ASCII (or `US7ASCII` in Oracle). So the conversion is only expecting ASCII characters, and is complaining about anything else.

The Oracle character set name corresponding to ISO-8859-1 is `WE8ISO8859P1`, so you need to supply the character set ID for that instead:

```
with q1 (Tdata) as (
  SELECT XMLtype(transportdata, nls_charset_id('WE8ISO8859P1')) from paymentinterchange
)
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d588ba089d1aaf034f393fbaa424df83) showing the same error you are getting and the successful query with the correct character set.

Comment: with q1 ( Tdata, paymentinterchangekey) AS (
  SELECT XMLtype(transportdata,1),
         paymentinterchangekey 
  from   bph_owner.paymentinterchange 
  where  paymentinterchangekey = '137630105'
)
select XMLQUERY(
         'declare default element namespace "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03";
         /Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/MsgId/text()'
         PASSING q1.Tdata
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ) AS msgid,
       q1.Tdata,
       q1.paymentinterchangekey "EE" 
from   q1; 
This has worked (after adding the ',1' to the xmltype function!

many thanks

Comment: So I have now run this as a generic SQL but get the following error :
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00216: invalid character 195 (0xC3)
Error at line 150
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 283
ORA-06512: at line 1
Is there a way to 'skip' malformed rows ? 
thanks again

Comment: They aren't malformed. I'd kept the `XMLType()` call you had, including the `,1` part. That is incorrect - you're telling Oracle the XML only contains ASCII characters, which is not the case. I've updated the answer to show how to pass the correct value to match the XML ISO-8859-1 declaration.

Comment: If I could buy you a beer I would - that worked, many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ca
n you please tell me how to extract the value of <S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02">

I need the value of the xmlns ?
Data looks like: 
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf xsi:schemaLocation="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf SCTScfBlkCredTrf.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:S2SCTScf="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf"><S2SCTScf:SndgInst>EBAPFRPA</S2SCTScf:SndgInst><S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02"><GrpHdr><MsgId>

Comment: Yes, you need to declare the namespace and refer to it in the XPath; [there's an example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67639356/266304). If you can't adapt it then please ask a new question, giving a complete and valid XML document rather than just a partial, malformed fragment. (I also notice the XML declaration is now UTF-8...)

Comment: Thanks- I will ask I new question as I cannot fit it all in here. I am trying to 'retrieve' the namespace (The Xml can contain pacs.008 or pacs.004 and I need to identify which).